# PLSQL procedures syntax

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

what wrong with this syntax:
I want to call to PROC_1 with 3 different parameters as:  10,15,100

```
Create Procedure PROC_1
(
age1 IN int,
age2 IN int,
age3 IN int
)
AS
BEGIN
IF age1 =  '10' THEN insert into ages (age) values (age1 );  END IF;
IF  age2 = '20' THEN insert into ages (age) values (age2); END IF;
IF  age3 ='100' THEN UPDATE ages set age = age3; END IF;
END PROC_1;
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? How does the ages table look like?

Comment: By the way, `'10'` is a string. `10` would be an integer.

Comment: What's wrong with the code? Do you get an error message from the compiler? If so provide the details. Do you get an error when running the code? If so, provide it. Does the code lead to an unexpected result? If so, what to you expect and what happens instead? Please take the time to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use proper types. I.e.

```
Create Procedure PROC_1
(
  age1 IN number,
  age2 IN number,
  age3 IN number
)
AS
BEGIN
  IF  age1 = 10 THEN insert into ages (age) values (age1 );  END IF;
  IF  age2 = 20 THEN insert into ages (age) values (age2); END IF;
  IF  age3 = 100 THEN UPDATE ages set age = age3; END IF;
END PROC_1;
```

Comment: I edited the question and I still have the same issue.

Comment: What issue is that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, by the parameters of your procedure, that the column is your table is of INT type,

```
SQL> create table ages(age int);

Table created.
```

the procedure syntax is correct:

```
SQL> CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_1(
  2                          age1    IN INT,
  3                          age2    IN INT,
  4                          age3    IN INT
  5                         ) AS
  6  BEGIN
  7      IF age1 = '10'
  8      THEN
  9          INSERT INTO ages(age)
 10               VALUES (age1);
 11      END IF;
 12
 13      IF age2 = '20'
 14      THEN
 15          INSERT INTO ages(age)
 16               VALUES (age2);
 17      END IF;
 18
 19      IF age3 = '100'
 20      THEN
 21          UPDATE ages
 22             SET age    = age3;
 23      END IF;
 24  END PROC_1;
 25  /

Procedure created.
```

And this is a way to call it:

```
SQL> begin
  2      PROC_1(10,15,100);
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

or even

```
SQL> exec PROC_1(10,15,100);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```